# Show wordpress posts in a grid - side by side divs

Tags: html, wordpress, css, wordpress-theming

I tried the code below to show posts in a grid , in  side by side manner. but , as shown in the image divs appear broken.

[image]

```
<?php

  $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 15, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => '' );

   $myposts = get_posts( $args );
   foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
     <div class="container"  style="width:960px;margin :opx auo;">

        <div class="colk" style="width:200px;height:150px;border-style:dotted;border-width:thin;display:inline-block;
float:left;clear:top;margin: 5px 20px 15px 0px;margin:10px;margin-top:0px;clear:top;" >

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">  <?php   the_title(); echo '<br>' ?> </a> 


  </div>
   </div>
 <?php echo '<br>'; ?>      
  <?php  endforeach;  ?>


  <?php
   wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
```

How  can i show the divs inline?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean by 'side by side' manner. If you want them to be aligned, then either float them all left, or better yet, since they all are `inline-block` add `vertical-align:top;` to them so they will all be aligned.

Comment: @dingo_d   ..it doesnt work..  i need to display all the divs side by side,, did u see the image?

Comment: If you mean in a line, then this won't work, since you are making them 200x150px and you only have a limited space in the container they're in (960px to be precise). If you want them all in line, your container must be larger than that...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 15, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => '' );

       $myposts = get_posts( $args );?>
        <div class="container"  style="width:960px;margin :0 auto;">
      <?php  foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>


            <div class="colk" style="width:200px;height:150px;border-tyle:dotted;border-width:thin;display:inline-block;float:left;clear:top;margin: 5px 20px 15px 0px;margin:10px;margin-top:0px;clear:top;" >

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">  <?php   the_title();?> </a> 


      </div>


      <?php  endforeach;  ?>
     </div>
```